# Convert React inline styles to CSS rules

Tags: css, reactjs

Is there a tool, that converts React inline style descriptions to CSS rules?

**Example input**:

```
{
    minHeight: 200,
    position: 'relative',
    flexGrow: 1,
    flexShrink: 1,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
}
```

**Example output**:

```
{
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
}
```

To put it differently, I want a tool that does the exact opposite of this: https://github.com/raphamorim/native-css

I would like to use it manually, so command line or web-based is preferable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes there's a tool that does just that!

https://glitch.com/~convert-css-js

If you paste your example input into the JS side (has to be in parentheses), you get the CSS output you specified (less the final semi-colon).

[image: glitch convert css to js screenshot]

Comment: Absurdly simple and effective!
Takes a little while to load. But man-oh-man, just what I was looking for! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this "A command line tool for JSS" https://github.com/cssinjs/cli

Comment: I tried to use it from command line, but couldn't make it work in 20 minuntes, so I had to step back. Thanks for pointing anyway!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a tool, that converts React inline style descriptions to CSS
>   rules?

There *is* a tool, yes. It's **Regular Expressions** (or **RegEx**).

If you want to transform the following:

- **nH => n-h** *(minHeight => min-height)*
- **xG => x-g** *(flexGrow => flex-grow)*
- **xS => x-s** *(flexShrink => flex-shrink)*
- **xD => x-d** *(flexDirection => flex-direction)*

This is the same Regex operation each time.

The pattern match is:

```
/([a-z])([A-Z])/
```

*ie. one lowercase letter followed by one uppercase letter, capturing each.*

The replacement is:

```
$1-\L$2
```

*ie.*

- keep the captured lowercase letter
- follow the captured lowercase letter with a hyphen
- follow the hyphen with a lowercase version of the captured uppercase letter

Comment: Hi Rounin! Thanks for the answer. I like your approach for simplicity, but it won't fit all the cases. For example, `flexDirection` should be converted to `flex-flow`, instead of `flex-direction`. I guess one needs to take the list of all such cases from React source code, to make a complete solution.

Comment: @sesm - `flex-flow` and `flex-direction` are different CSS rules. `flex-flow` is a shorthand to set both `flex-direction` and `flex-wrap` at once (since they go hand-in-hand). React supports all three of these via `flexFlow`, `flexDirection`, and `flexWrap`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow

Comment: @cchamberlain thanks for you comment, I didn't know this. This actually makes a regexp approach viable.

Comment: NP! I was trying to find a tool that did this the other day. Agree regex might be best bet.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this tool for converting : https://casbin.org/CssToAndFromReact/