# How to write inline css in string rather than object?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, sass, next.js13

Is there any way to write inline css in string rather than object format?

I tried this but it obviously didn't work:

```
<div style={"color:red;font-weight:bold"}> Hello there </div>
```

---

#### Why am I doing this?

I usually write some inline css first and once it looks good in the browser I copy paste that inline into my `.scss` file
but if I use objects I'll first have to convert them into css format and then paste them into my file which would be really tedious

( **Note:** If it is not possible I'm also open to using a vscode extension which converts object into css )

Comment: You can try this or the CSS-in-JS extension.
    `const myStyle = {
      color: 'red',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    };
    
    const inlineStyle = Object.entries(myStyle)
      .map(([property, value]) => `${property}:${value}`)
      .join(';');
    
    return <div style={inlineStyle}>Hello there</div>;`

Comment: @Konrad Not really that doesn't solve my main question and is more of a workaround (but still appreciated)

Comment: @cak3_lover - FWIW, if your "main question" is "is it possible to use a string instead," the answer is "no." So a workaround is the best you're going to get.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder then please post it as a solution :)

Comment: You can also take a look at https://dev.to/qausim/convert-html-inline-styles-to-a-style-object-for-react-components-2cbi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use a string instead, not without a workaround that may be more effort than it's worth.¹ From [the documentation](https://react.dev/learn/typescript#typing-style-props):

> When using inline styles in React, you can use React.CSSProperties to describe the object passed to the style prop. This type is a union of all the possible CSS properties, and is a good way to ensure you are passing valid CSS properties to the style prop, and to get auto-complete in your editor.
>
> ```
> interface MyComponentProps {
>   style: React.CSSProperties;
> }
> ```

In the comments, [Konrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad) pointed to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773163/convert-react-inline-styles-to-css-rules), which has an answer linking to [a tool](https://glitch.com/%7Econvert-css-js) that converts between the two formats.

---

¹ For instance, Konrad also found and linked to [this blog post](https://dev.to/qausim/convert-html-inline-styles-to-a-style-object-for-react-components-2cbi) which shows code for a function that converts a string to an object at runtime. So you *could* do `style={theFunction("your styles")}`. But aside from unnecessary complication, that would involve re-converting the string on every render (unless you memoized it, which costs memory and even more complexity...). Still, it's an option.

Comment: stupid question but I gotta ask, will next.js ever support inline css as strings or is there any proposal to add it?

Comment: @cak3_lover - I wouldn't know. The place to ask would probably be their issue list.

Answer (score 1):

Incase anyone was wondering I ended up using [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jimmy-huang.css-in-js-converter)

It was the only one which seemed to be working for me ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -3):

Don't Use Object, Just use like this

```
<div style="color:red;font-weight:bold"> Hello there </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-germain-3jstt4?file=/src/App.js *The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.*